# In a hive query can you specify a condition like "where coulm1 is INT"?

Tags: hive

I would like to query a hive table only for those rows that have coulmn1 as integer value only. Due to some data corruption, without this check I am getting a lot of junk data, I would like to get rid of that data by applying where column1 is INT kind of condition, but I couldn't find anything like that in hive. Could anyone suggest how I could do it?

Answer (score 0):

Without any example data, I would suggest something very basic like this:

- define column `X` as STRING
- check that `X = cast(cast(X as INT) as STRING)`

You may have to add some tolerance to blank space, zero-padding, etc. depending on the way your "integers" are actually formatted.

Comment: Found a solution that is working : 
I could add a Double number check like below, anything other than just numbers will make it null. Also, the valid numbers for the column will never cross the Double range.
So we could do something like below I guess:

"select * from table_example where cast(column1 as double) is not null"

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that is working : 
I could add a Double number check like below, anything other than just numbers will make it null. Also, the valid numbers for the column will never cross the Double range.
So we could do something like below I guess:

"select * from table_example where cast(column1 as double) is not null"